# ASP.Net application error 4005: The authentication ticker is invalid

Tags: asp.net, forms, authentication

We have an ASP.Net 3.5 application which has been running for about 5 years with no problems. We have recently come across a problem:

We have moved a user and a new PC to a remote location which is connectedto the main site via VPN. from there the user is accessing the web application and logging in as normal, but when trying to submit a request to the server, we get error in the web server log:

> Event code: 4005  Event message: Forms authentication failed for the
>   request. Reason: The ticket supplied was invalid.

We have also connected a new PC (running IE9) to the same location, and this PC works fine. The PC presenting the problem is using IE8, which is what the rest of the PCs use in the main site.

Can somebody assist in troubleshooting this issue? Is there a setting on `IE8` I can check?

Answer (score 0):

> Did u try adding the following keys in your web.config file under `<appSettings>`.

```
<add key="aspnet:UseLegacyEncryption" value="true" />
<add key="aspnet:UseLegacyFormsAuthenticationTicketCompatibility" value="true" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment; I have tried these lines but I still get the same result.